# Gitlab:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

I get this error on a fresh install of gitlab. The message looks like:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-
token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.example.com/something.git/': Peer's 
Certificate issuer is not recognized.ERROR: Job 
failed: exit status 1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Had faced the same problem after enabling verbose mode by following command 
`export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and found the following issue:

**NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)**

Found this following site helpful,But its good when you have entire control for 
the proxy server as well to enter the certificates.

http://dropbit.com/?p=168

I instead ran following command to bypass ssl verification by porxy server and it worked

```
git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
```

Comment: I do not wat to disable  ssl.

Comment: Disabling SSL is not the appropriate answer. It is a workaround, and should only be used with caution.

Comment: true, the appropriate answer is for the project to improve / redesign runners.

Answer (score 7):

You need to configure `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.
Change this line

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/<your-local-path>/cert.pem"
```

to

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/<your-local-path>/fullchain.pem"
```

(Assuming, you already have `nginx` enabled and you have correctly issued certificates, e.g. from LetsEncrypt.)

then restart gitlab and you're done:

```
$ gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Why - `cert.pem` does not contain full certificate chain, thus ca chain cannot be verified. Replacing with `fullchain.pem` solves it.

Comment: worked for me. I had this error after upgrading gitlab-runner from version 9.* to 12.*

Comment: thanks for the helpful workaround. i have to say i'm so utterly sick of gitlab's chaotic design, i don't even find words for it anymore. i.e. the problem isn't that cert.pem doesn't hold the full chain but that they don't load the chain, or rather that they don't have a mechanism to sync certs, etc, etc.