# Gitlab : Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I have a on-prem gitlab where I am trying to run some builds/pipeline but getting the below error -

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.systems/testing/test-project-poc.git/': Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
```

I have already looked into this - [Gitlab:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608595/gitlabpeers-certificate-issuer-is-not-recognized) and followed the steps of obtaining the `.pem` file by merging the `server certificate`, `intermediate certificate` and `root certificate` but I am still getting the below error and really struggling to find the root cause.

`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb config`

```
##! enable/disable 2-way SSL client authentication
#nginx['ssl_verify_client'] = "off"

##! if ssl_verify_client on, verification depth in the client certificates chain
#nginx['ssl_verify_depth'] = "1"

nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.systems.pem"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.systems.key"
```

Is there any other configuration which i need to update/modify? Any guidance is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing you are using a self signed certificate. If that is the case you have two options to rectify this issue:

1. Recommended option: Here again I assume that you have already solved the issue between the gitlab-runner and gitlab itself, hence you registered the runner successfully. So you have already the certificate file in /etc/gitlab-runner/certs. So on the server hosting the gitlab-runner, run the below command:

   ```
   git config --system http.sslCAInfo /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/CERITIFICATE_NAME.crt
   ```
2. This is unsafe: Here you just disable the git https certificate verification:

   ```
   git config --system http.sslverify false
   ```

Comment: Option number 1 here solved my "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized" problem.

Comment: The only issue I had here with option 1 is that the "gitlab-runner" user didn't have permissions to read the /etc/gitlab-runner directory

Answer (score 0):

My /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/blablabl.cer had to have the complete chain/root as per https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html - which is a little weird since the production server has the smaller one and works. Restarted the runner.